# Sqlite trigger to updated a row in one table after delete of the row in different table

Tags: android, sqlite

In android using trigger, I am trying to update a value in table A depending on the matching row id (id) when a row is deleted in table B:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_card_on_delete AFTER DELETE ON TABLE_B 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE TABLE_A set card= "-1" where TABLE_B.id = TABLE_A.id;
END;
```

but while executing it it gives me error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: TABLE_B.id (code 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no table named `TABLE_B` in the UPDATE statement.

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) says:

> Both the WHEN clause and the trigger actions may access elements of the row being inserted, deleted or updated using references of the form "NEW.*column-name*" and "OLD.*column-name*", where column-name is the name of a column from the table that the trigger is associated with.

Replace `TABLE_B.id` with `OLD.id`.